VM Centos7 Inside Proxmox Can't resize storage
i have a Centos7 VM with 100% capacity used for storage dev/mapper/sinta--vg-root

in cfdisk, i have free storage about 120GB, i want to make the dev/mapper/sinta--vg-root more bigger, but first i want to resize the dev/sda5 into max size available, but it's error

How to solve this?

Because /dev/sda5 is logical partition, located in /dev/sda2 you should first extend sda2 and then sda5. The other way is to create new logical partition in sda2 and add this new partition in the VG.
